# Understanding Set Notation

Tags: analysis, elementary-set-theory, notation

I'm having some trouble understanding a definition and explanation in my textbook *Introduction to Analysis by Edward Gaughan 5th edition*. The book begins with some preliminary information about sets and some of the information is sort of confusing and I have a feeling that in this sort of class if you don't understand the basics you are doomed. So hopefully somebody out there can help me understand the confusing bits a little better.

So the definition in question is as follows:

> Let $\Lambda$ be a set, and suppose for each $\lambda \in \Lambda$, a subset $A_{\lambda}$ of a given set S is specified. The collection of sets $A_{\lambda}$ is called an *indexed family* of subsets of S with $\Lambda$ as the index set. We denote this by ${\{ A \}}_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$
>
> If ${\{ A \}}_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$ is an indexed family of sets, define
>
> $\cap_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$ $A_{\lambda}$ = {x : x $\in A_{\lambda}$ for all $\lambda \in \Lambda$}
>
> $\cup_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$ $A_{\lambda}$ = {x : x $\in A_{\lambda}$ for some $\lambda \in \Lambda$}

Alright so the definition above I thought was straightforward, but then the text goes on to say this:

> There is one logical difficulty here that needs to be pointed out. **If $\Lambda$ is the empty set, then it is easy to see that $\cup_{\lambda \in \Lambda} A_{\lambda}$ is empty; however, it is not clear what to expect of $\cap_{\lambda \in \Lambda} A_{\lambda}$.**

The bolded explanation is what I do not understand. If $\Lambda$ is the empty set there will be no subsets to union because there are no elements $\lambda \in \Lambda$ but why is it not clear that $\cap_{\lambda \in \Lambda} A_{\lambda}$ is also empty, won't there also be no subsets $A_{\lambda}$ to seek the intersection of??

The text ends with the following conclusion:

> In a context where all sets considered are understood to be subsets of a given set S, the common usage is to let:
>
> S = $\cap_{\lambda \in \oslash} A_{\lambda}$

Any information would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition $x\in\bigcap_{\lambda\in\Lambda}A_\lambda$ if and only if $x\in A_\lambda$ for all $\lambda\in\Lambda$. Turn that around: what does it mean to say that $x\notin\bigcap_{\lambda\in\Lambda}A_\lambda$? It must mean that there is some $\lambda\in\Lambda$ such that $x\notin A_\lambda$. To put it a little differently, suppose that someone gave you an $x$ and asked you to prove that $x\notin\bigcap_{\lambda\in\Lambda}A_\lambda$; how could you do it? The only sure way seems to be to find some $\lambda\in\Lambda$ such that $x\notin A_\lambda$. But if $\Lambda=\varnothing$, you can’t even find a $\lambda\in\Lambda$, let alone one with the further property that $x\notin A_\lambda$. Thus, when $\Lambda=\varnothing$ **there is no way to show that some** $x\notin\bigcap_{\lambda\in\Lambda}A_\lambda$!

On the face of it this would seem to show that **every** $x$ belongs to $\bigcap_{\lambda\in\Lambda}A_\lambda$. Unfortunately, that ultimately leads to [Russell’s paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_paradox), so we can’t allow it. The best we can do is take $\bigcap_{\lambda\in\Lambda}A_\lambda$ to be the set of all objects in the universe of discourse, Gaughan’s set $S$.

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense to me

Comment: @Ockham: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 1):

If we have the index set being empty, then 
$$ \bigcap_{\lambda \in \Lambda} A_\lambda = \{x :  x \in A_\lambda\text{ for all }\lambda \in \emptyset \}.$$

The problem here is that the statement $x \in A_\lambda$ for all $\lambda \in \emptyset$  is *vacuously* true, and so *all* x satisfy it. The question then becomes, what do we mean by *all* $x$? This is why it's helpful to establish some superset that we assume we're working in. This super set is the S referred to in the book, and this takes the place of *all $x$*.

Answer (score 1):

We have $x\in \bigcup A_\lambda$ iff there exists a $\lambda\in \Lambda$ with $x\in A_\lambda$. If there exists no $\lambda$ at all, there certainly exists no lambda with $x\in A_\lambda$. Hence $x\in\bigcup A_\lambda$ is **false** for whatever $x$ we check. Hence the set contains **nothing**, it is the empty set.

We should have $x\in \bigcap A_\lambda$ iff for all $\lambda\in \Lambda$ we have $x\in A_\lambda$. But since $\Lambda$ is empty, *anything* is true about the elements of $\Lambda$, e.g. each element of $\Lambda$ is a green-eyed fyling pig. Especially $x\in A_\lambda$ is true for all $\lambda$, hence  $x\in\bigcap A_\lambda$ is **true** for whatever $x$ we check. Hence the set contains **everyhing**.
However there is no such thing as a "set of everything".
Well, there *is* a set of everything in limited constexts, as the conclusion of your text writes: If your objects of discourse are only the elements of $S$ then it is valid to say that "everything" refers to all elements of $S$, i.e. $S$ itself. As this notion of $\bigcap A_\lambda$ varies with $S$, there is no *general* notion of it for empty $\Lambda$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $\Lambda = \varnothing$. Let $x$ be a set. Then, for some $\lambda \in \Lambda$, we have $x \notin A_{\lambda}$. Since $\Lambda = \varnothing$ there is no such $\lambda$. Thus $x \in \cap \{ A_{\lambda} \colon \lambda \in \varnothing \} $. Thus $\cap \{ A_{\lambda} \colon \lambda \in \varnothing \} $ has every set as an element. A more common approach to the empty union is to consider $A_{\lambda} \subseteq B$ for all $\lambda$ and let $\cap$ be an operator on the complete lattice of subsets of $B$. In this case the $x$ we used above is required to be an element of $B$. The empty intersection will be $B$. In practice the $A_{\lambda}$ are coming from somewhere and $B$ is a set in question that contains all of the $A_{\lambda}$.